# What is wrong with my bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=app

# Execute exe1
pathToExe1=./dir1/exe1
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=app -t "exe1" -- $pathToExe1

# Execute exe2
pathToExe2=./dir2/exe2
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=app -t "exe2" -- $pathToExe2

# Execute exe3
pathToExe3=./dir3/exe3
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=app -t "exe3" -- $pathToExe3

# Execute exe4
pathToExe4=./dir4/exe4
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
do
    arg="argValue${i}"
    gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=app -t "exe4" -- $pathToExe4 $arg
done
```

I am trying to open a new terminal window which has a bunch of terminal tabs, each of which is running a executable. It won't run... What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway to do it without using profiles? When I do create a profile called "app", it opens another window, but the tabs open in the original window. Which is not right.

Comment: Please fix your script, use `var=value` instead of `var = value` or `var= value`. If a script is not working it is useful using `set -x` to get an output what is actually executed

Comment: ok I changed it. Could you please tell me why my script is not working.

Comment: Although not an answer to your original question , but it can be easily done via the "Konsole" terminal : "konsole --new-tab -e "some command" & konsole --new-tab -e "another command" & .

Comment: If I run a code similar to yours in gnome-terminal , it works as you expected , but if I run it from another terminal ( like Konsole ) it will open up multiple gnome-terminal windows.I'm running ubuntu 18 . Which version do you use ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18 as well (I am using gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I think your script hangs waiting for the first `gnome-terminal` command to finish.

Try to add a space then <kbd>&</kbd> at the end of each `gnome-terminal` line, so the shell will not wait there and continue.